# how to select one elements before I choose

Tags: jquery

things like so, how to make my input:hidden get an default value before click.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .choose {
    color: red;
    } 
    span.google a {
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.10.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $('.google').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
        var obj = $('.google a');
            $(this).toggleClass('choose').siblings().removeClass('choose');
            var selectVal = $(this).text();
            var selectId = $(this).data('id');
            $('input[type="hidden"]').val(selectVal);
            $('input[type="hidden"]').attr('data-id', selectId);
    });
    }); 
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <span class="google">

    <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-id="1">google</a>
    <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-id="2">yahoo</a>
    <a href="javascript: void(0);" data-id="3">facebook</a>
    </span>
    <input type="hidden" name="send" value="" data-id="" />
    <!-- //here is an input to contain the data-id from one of element a -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

after trying it many times, I can't solve it. Help me!
Here is my code on jsfiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/WbPEV/](http://jsfiddle.net/WbPEV/2/)

Now I check my question clean.Pardon my english weak!Can you help me?

Comment: what is "data-id"...?

Comment: like <a href ="#" data-id="">,get its data to the input

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(function() {
    $('.google').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
        var obj = $('.google a');
        $(this).toggleClass('choose').siblings().removeClass('choose');
        $('#inputElement').val($(this).data("id"));
        console.log($(this).get());
    });
});
```

your updated jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zahirdhada/WbPEV/3/

Comment: what do you mean by "default value before click"?

Comment: default value means that before click, the first a element was selected and the element get its data-id and a.text. This is I means

Comment: can you explain with an example?

Answer (score 0):

Please check

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/wMWqT/]
```

I hope It will help you.